# Fantasy Movie ID with Cat Lady

Tags: story-identification, b-movies

I saw this movie in the summer of 1998, on TV.  It was definitely low budget, but it has stuck with me ever since and I would love to see it again.

The things I remember for sure:

- The main character is a young boy with blond curly hair and his dog
- His home and family are somehow destroyed, and he leaves to avenge
  them.
- He meets an old man tinkerer and a blue cat woman who help him
  on his way.
- At some point he is put in a cage with an ogre child. The cage hangs in the air and there are bones all around.
- He is taken to a mine where he is forced to dig for crystals with the other
  slaves, and an old woman sacrifices herself for him by throwing herself into an infinite pit.

I hope this is enough to trigger a memory in someone. Thank you!

This is a live action movie.

*Additional notes:*

I've questioned whether these memories are from the same movie, so I didn't include them at first, but since no one found the answer I'm going to add them.  Please don't consider any of these details as necessary parts of a potential answer:

The main character's family and village were destroyed by an army who came in silver spaceships.  Huts were burned down, but somehow the boy and his dog escaped.  I remember a superimposed shot where the boy is crying in the foreground while the destruction happens.  In the end, there is a confrontation in a silvery sci-fi throne room, with an evil king who does not care about his people.  The guards carry long staff weapons that shoot energy beams and are powered by the crystals the enslaved workers were mining.  The movie ends with the main character and his companions venturing off across a rocky landscape, heading on unknown adventures after succeeding in their quest.

Comment: The 1972 version of the French film *Le Petit Poucel* is a partial match. Blond child, ogres. But that's pretty much as far as it goes. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJ6IY_gQqPE

Comment: Concerning blue cat woman do you refer to the some kind of suit or she was some specie looking like a human-cat mix of a blue color?

Comment: From what I recall, the cat woman was wearing blue body paint, had cat ears, a tail, and other makeup features, but not fur.

Comment: Can you recall if it was an older film or was it from the 90s?

Comment: I would guess that it was made in the 80s or early 90s, but I'm really not sure.

Comment: Take a look at [The Adventures Of Captain Zoom In Outer Space](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uj1VWBy_LY), there are some features you have mentioned, so it could be the second movie.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Captain Zoom looks like fun! The movie I'm looking for was not a comedy, though.

Comment: Take a look at "Krull" movie also, there are crystals, corresponding weapons, boy with a dog, similar final scene: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o0PcV_uUvE8